# How can I add javascript to a PDF document to count the number of checked boxes and enter the value into a textbox area?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

So I have a PDF doc that has 25 check boxes called "cb1" through "cb25".  I would like to be able to count the number of boxes that are checked and put that count into a text box area called "Points".

I'm not very familiar with either JS or PDF form creation but from what I've been able to dig up I think I'm close to getting it to work.

I have added the following code to the document level:

```js
function CountCheckBoxes(aFieldsNames) {
    // count field names that have been selected
    var count = 0;
    // loop through array of field names
    for (i = 0; i < aFieldNames.length; i++) {
      // for field names with a value of not Off increment counter
      if (this.getField(aFieldNames[i]).value != "Off") count++;
    } // end loop of field names
    // return count
    return count;
  } // end CountCheckBoxes
```

I've tried adding the following code text box properties to execute JS on mouse up and as a calculated value, neither of which seem to work to populate the text box with a count of checked boxes.

```js
// var define field names to be tested
var aFields = new Array('cb1', 'cb2', 'cb3', 'cb4', 'cb5', 'cb6', 'cb7', 'cb8', 'cb9', 'cb10', 'cb11', 'cb12', 'cb13', 'cb14', 'cb14', 'cb15', 'cb16', 'cb17', 'cb18', 'cb19', 'cb20', 'cb21', 'cb22', 'cb23', 'cb24', 'cb25');
// count field names that have been selected
event.value = CountCheckBoxes(aFields);
```

Comment: Note that event.value is the value going into the field from which the script is called; if it is a button, the result goes nowhere, because the Button does not have a value property; you'd have to add the code to the text field where the sum should appear. Then it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should be added to the text field that keeps count of the boxes. To do so, right click on the form field then Properties -> Calculate -> Custom Calculation Script -> "Edit...".

```
var sum = 0;
for ( i = 1; i < 26; i++ ) {
        f = "cb" + i;
        field = getField(f);
        if (field.isBoxChecked(0)) {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
    }
event.value = sum;
```

This is tested and working in an actual document. Here are some details about the code:

There is a loop that goes over all 25 fields, and creates a string for each one of their names. The string values are "cb1", "cb2" etc. Then gets the field by name. The `isBoxChecked(0)` field method, will return true if the box is checked. If a box is checked, the code will bump up the sum of all checked fields. When it's all done, the sum is assigned to the current text field.

[Here is a link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) to the JS for Acrobat reference. It's quite useful when putting together samples like the one above.

Comment: Thanks.  This works  but but with one minor issue...  with no boxes checked it is starting the count at 1 and always is 1 higher than the actual number of checked boxes.  I can always just subtract one from the event.value but I don't see in the code why the count would be off.

Comment: Try setting the default value of the field to "0". It's in the "Options" tab. I tested it with 5 boxes and it come out correct.

Comment: NVM... There must have been a checked box that wasn't visible because I reset the form and it's accurate now.

Comment: A little warning about the isBoxChecked(): It works reliably only when there is exactly one widget of the checkbox; if there are multiple widgets (checkboxes with same name but different return values, or radiobuttons), the numbering of the widgets may be erratic, and in such a case, you better use the field.value approach.