# Calculating a rating with N/A as an option

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abayevsky/x9d7ca1d/1/).

I am trying to

1. Calculate an average rating based on 2-6 responses (answers can be:
   `0, 1, 2` or `NA`, and are called `"1a", "1b", "1c", "2a"`, etc). I have a
   script that averages the ratings correctly, but produces `"0"`
   whenever all answers are `"NA"`. I need the produced average to also
   be `"NA"` whenever all answers are `"NA"`.

   This is the code that I have:

   ```
   var aField = new Array("1a", "1b", "1c")  //create an array of the fields you need to check the value of

   var aScore = new Array();  //creating an empty array for further use

   var nScore = 0;  //creating a variable holding the sum of the scores
   for (var i = 0; i < aField.length; i++){ //looping through every item of array aField

    if (this.getField(aField[i]).value >= 0){  //if our value is a number eliminating 0, nothing and NA

         aScore.push(aField[i]);  //we will count the number of correct values with this array;

         nScore += Number(this.getField(aField[i]).value);  //  we add the value to our total
    }
   }

   if (aScore.length >0){  //We don't want to divide our score by 0 because it's impossible

    event.value = nScore/aScore.length;  //we devide the result by the number of correct values in the array.
   ```

   Someone suggested the following code to solve the problem, but when
   I ran it, I received a

   "SyntaxError: missing; before statement 12:
       at line 13"

   message. (Not sure what the problem is, but if anyone
   can find it/fix the code, greatly appreciated).

   ```
   var allFieldsAreNA = true;


   for (var i = 0; i < aField.length; i++){
   if ( this.getField(aField[i]).value >= 0 ) {
     allFieldsAreNA = false;
     break;
   }
   }


   If( allFieldsAreNA == false ) {

   // do the code you already have

   }
   else {
   event.value = “NA”; // or something like that
   }
   ```
2. I need to get a script that takes the average rating and multiplies it by various `"Weight Factors"` (eg, `0.15, 0.1`, etc). If the avg. rating is a number, then it simply multiplies, if the avg. rating is `"NA"` then the `"Weighted Rating"` is also `"NA"`.
3. A script to sum all `"Weighted Ratings"` and divide by total `"Weight Factors"`. If all fields are calculated to be numbers, then total Weight Factors is `1.0` or `100%` (`.1, .15, .15, .1, .15, .25, .1`), and total `"Weighted Ratings"` divided by `1.0` equals... If there is a Weighted Rating that is `NA`, then total `"Weight Factors"` should be calculated accordingly (Weighted Rating of category `6 is NA`, therefore `Weight Factors` should only be `.1 + .15 +.15 + .1 + .15 + .1`), and total `"Weighted Ratings" / 0.75`.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second batch of code in the OP should identify if all fields have "NA" as values, and set the `allFieldsAreNA` variable to `true` if that's the case. It looks like the problem in the code is in this line `If( allFieldsAreNA == false ) {`. The `if` statement is capitalized, and it should start with a lower case `i`.

It should be fairly easy from here to print out "NA" for the calculations that need to be done.

The third part of the OP question is a bit confusing. It would seem pretty easy to calculate once the `allFieldsAreNA` variable is populated though.

There is a similar question about JS in a PDF that I answer some time ago. The code there could also be used as a reference. It does similar calculations in a form. [Count checkboxes in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642688/how-can-i-add-javascript-to-a-pdf-document-to-count-the-number-of-checked-boxes/34643123#34643123)